# Selection Sort Issues

Tags: java, selection-sort

I have an issue with the following code where I try to enter a list of words (Alpha, delta, Charlie, beta) and sort them; however, the list sorts all capitals first and then lowercase like (Alpha, Charlie, beta, delta) even though I just want it to sort alphabetically in general i.e. -> (Alpha, beta, Charlie, delta)

Please find my code for the selection sort attached below:

```
public void sortPokemon()
    {
    Pokemon temp;
    for(int i = 1; i < amount; i++){
        for(int j = i; j > 0; j--){
            if(pokemon[j].getSpecies().compareTo(pokemon[j-1].getSpecies()) < 0){
                    temp = pokemon[j];
                    pokemon[j] = pokemon[j-1];
                    pokemon[j-1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Regular String.compareTo works that way only. What you need is a custom comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You can either implement a Comparator, there, you compare strings with case ignored, something like:

```
public class IgnoreCaseComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
         return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Or you can put your strings in a map (TreeMap maybe), key is lowercase(or upper) string, value is your original string.

Note that the Map way doesn't allow same keys.

Comment: Or use the built-in [String#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).

Answer (score 0):

String.compareTo honor the case too. You can make Pokemon implements Comparable something like this:

```
public class Pokemon implements Comparable<Pokemon> {
    // you other methods here

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pokemon p) {
        return this.getSpecies().toLowercase().compareTo(p.getSpecies().toLowercase());
    }
}
```

Then you can do direct comparison like this:

```
if(pokemon[j].compareTo(pokemon[j-1]))
```

You can also use a custom Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code (edit your `if statement`) Use 
    `compareToIgnoreCase()` method defined in `String.java` class. The method is present from java 1.2 onwards.

`if(pokemon[j].getSpecies().compareToIgnoreCase(pokemon[j-1].getSpecies()) <  0)`

Note that by using `compareTo()` method and converting Strings case to upper or lower in a loop will become a performace wise bad with Strings. But same will be the case by using other ways which are Making your `Pokemon` class implement `Comparable` interface and returning appropriate value from `compareTo` method. Same will be the case with class extending Comparator

Answer (score 0):

Since All Your Input Are of String Data Type, hence you can easily sort them by using the inbuilt methods on ignore case present in java library.